# How to call a simple function and simultaneously run the following line(s)?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I know there is something called thread, but I am confused by those complex information all over Google. `myFunc()` takes a little time (not computationally expensive, say play a short mp3 file).

What I want to do is call `myFunc()` and don't need to wait for it to return to run the following lines of code. Furthermore, I don't need to keep anything related to `myFunc(arg)`, I only need it to be executed only.

```py
while(True):
    ......
    myFunc(arg)
    ###some
    ###lines
    ###of
    ###code
```

Sorry for my bad English. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```py
from threading import Thread

def myFunc(arg):
    # run code here

while(True):
    thread = Thread(target = myFunc, args = (arg, ))
    thread.start() # starts the thread, executes the function
    ###some
    ###lines
    ###of
    ###code
    thread.join() # wait for myFunc to finish
```

You can do similarly with processes instead of threads.

Might want take a look into pools if you want to perform a list of arguments with the same function. You can call `imap` and iterate the results and call the rest of the code.

Comment: I've tried it, but it is not I am expected(I made join() right before a new thread). Since myFunc() takes approximately 1 to 2 seconds, I still see some lags when the program is running(join() still has to wait slightly less 1 to 2 seconds)

Comment: @DeanChong, I am not sure how many times you are going to call new threads, since you are executing within a while(True) loop. I suspect there is a break or return in there. If you want to call chunks of threads at a time, please check out pools (in your case, ThreadPool). That may help decrease the time interval between each iteration.

Comment: I've simply used a queue and solve this problem(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61200617/how-to-play-different-sound-consecutively-and-asynchronously-in-python/61201058#61201058). Thanks anyway!